# Python web framework suggestion for a web service

Tags: python, json, web-services, web-frameworks

I'm gonna write a web service which will allow upload/download of files, managing permissions and users. It will be the interface to which a Desktop app or Mobile App will communicate. I was wondering which of the web frameworks I should use to to that?

It is a sort of remote storage for media files.

I am going to host the web service on EC2 in a Linux environment. It should be fast (obviously) because It will have to handle tens of requests per second, transferring lots of data (GBs)... Communication will be done using JSon... But how to deal with binary data? If I use base64, it will grow by 33%...

I think web2py should be ok, because it is very stable and mature project, but wanted other suggestions before choosing.

Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to say that the project's not gonna be the next DropBox or Google Drive. It will just replace an old backup service the company I'm working at is offering to customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no doubt going to be shot down for this answer, but it needs to be said...

You're going to write a service that allows tens of transfers a second, with very large file sizes... Uptime is going to be essential and so is transfer speeds etc...

If this is for a business, and not just a personal pet project get the personal responsible for the IT budget to give "Box" or "DropBox" some pennies and use their services (I am *not* affiliated with either company).

On a business level, this gets you up and running straight off, would probably end up cheaper than you coding, designing, debugging, paying for EC2 etc...

More related to your question:

`Flask` seems to be an up-coming and usable "simple" framework. That should provide all the functionality without all the *bells and whistles*.

The other I would spend time looking at would be `Pyramid` - which when using a very basic starter template is very simple, but you've got the machinery behind it to really get quite complex things done. (You can mix url dispatch and traversal where necessary for instance).

Comment: Flask may be a good choice. I also heard of CherryPy, which seems to be complete and lightweight at the same time.